# How can I test this Angular 2 service?

Tags: testing, typescript, angular

I have the following service in my Angular application:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getList() {
    return this.http.get('/api/books.json');
  }
}
```

How would I test the `getList()` function?

I don't need every last detail, just some general direction. I assume this is pretty well-worn territory but I'm having trouble finding documentation on how people normally go about testing something like this. Once I know the direction to go, I can probably chase down the details myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed around with it some more on my own. Here's what I came up with for the test itself:

```
  it('should assign a list of books', inject([BookService, MockBackend, Http], (bookService, backend, http) => {
    backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
      var mockResponse = new Response(new ResponseOptions({
        body: [{ name: 'Whiteboard Interviews' }]
      }));
      connection.mockRespond(mockResponse);
    });

    let service = new BookService(http);
    service.getList().subscribe(response => {
      expect(response.json()).toEqual([{ name: 'Whiteboard Interviews' }]);
    });
  }));
```

And here's the full spec file:

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';

import {
  Http,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  Response,
  ResponseOptions,
  BaseRequestOptions,
  ConnectionBackend
} from '@angular/http';

import {
  beforeEach, beforeEachProviders,
  describe, xdescribe,
  expect, it, xit,
  async, inject
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { BookService } from './book.service';

describe('Book Service', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    BookService,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    provide(Http, {
      useFactory: function (backend:ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions:BaseRequestOptions) {
        return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
      },
      deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
    })
  ]);

  it('should ...',
      inject([BookService], (service: BookService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should assign a list of books', inject([BookService, MockBackend, Http], (bookService, backend, http) => {
    backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
      var mockResponse = new Response(new ResponseOptions({
        body: [{ name: 'Whiteboard Interviews' }]
      }));
      connection.mockRespond(mockResponse);
    });

    let service = new BookService(http);
    service.getList().subscribe(response => {
      expect(response.json()).toEqual([{ name: 'Whiteboard Interviews' }]);
    });
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import {addProviders, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('my code', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([
      BookService, 
      HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      MockBackend,
      {provide: XHRBackend, useExiting: MockBackend}]);
  });

  it('does stuff', inject([BookService], (service) => {
    // actual test
  });
});
```

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/MockBackend-class.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this helps shed some light on the subject although the part I was more interested in what what goes _inside_ the `it` :). I've created a separate question that describes what I'm currently trying. Maybe once that's sorted out we could splice the solution into this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484765/angular-2-mock-response-not-working